# Based on one key value from array how to find value of other key?

Tags: javascript

[image: Reponse format]

```
 data.filter((el)=>{
    if(el.column_name == e.target.value){
      el.data_type
    }

  })
```

I am having the data as shared in screenshot based on column name key i need to find data_type

Comment: Can you please ask you question differently ? Don't understand what you try to do

Comment: `data.find((el)=> el.column_name == e.target.value).data_type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the object with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (or take a default empty one) and then access the wanted property.

```
type = (array.find(el => el.column_name === e.target.value) || {}).data_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) must return a boolean to include or not the record in the new array;

If you need a whole new array, consider using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map) or [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce)

```
const newData = groups.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (el.column_name === e.target.value) {
    acc.push(el.data_type);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

If you just need a value, you can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find)

```
const dataType = data.find(el=>el.column_name === e.target.value).data_type;
```